# OpenCV pytorch prediction error with onnx model

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch, onnx

My codes are here. I made a model for the prediction of cell and converted it to onnx then load with OpenCV to predicted with OpenCV but went somethings wrong

###### Libraries

```
import cv2
import torchvision.models as models
import torch.onnx
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import numpy as np
```

###### Onnx and model

```
original_model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)

opencv_net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX('resnet50.onnx')
```

###### Opencv prediction

```
opencv_net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX('resnet50.onnx')
input_img=cv2.imread('image.bmp',cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
input_img=input_img.astype(np.float32)
input_img=cv2.resize(input_img,(256,256))

mean=np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406]) * 255.0
scale=1/255.0
std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
input_blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(
    image=input_img,
    scalefactor=scale,
    size=(224, 224),  # img target size
    mean=mean,
    #swapRB=True,  # BGR -> RGB
    crop=True  # center crop
)

input_blob[0] /= np.asarray(std, dtype=np.float32).reshape(3, 1, 1)
print("Input blob shape: {}\n".format(input_blob.shape))
preproc_img=input_blob

opencv_net.setInput(preproc_img)
out = opencv_net.forward()
print("OpenCV DNN prediction: \n")
print("* shape: ", out.shape)

test_class_id = np.argmax(out)

test_labels=opencv_net.getLayerNames()
#print((test_labels))

confidence = out[0][test_class_id]
print("* class ID: {}, label: {}".format(test_class_id, test_labels[test_class_id]))
print("* confidence: {:.4f}".format(confidence))
```

###### Opencv predictions output

```
OpenCV DNN prediction: 

* shape:  (1, 2)
* class ID: 1, label: 323
* confidence: 8.4153
```

###### **!!!Problem is here!!!  Pytorch inference**

```
original_model.eval()
preproc_img = torch.FloatTensor(preproc_img)
# inference
out = original_model(preproc_img)

print("\nPyTorch model prediction: \n")
print("* shape: ", out.shape)

test_class_id = torch.argmax(out, axis=1).item()
print("* class ID: {}, label: {}".format(test_class_id, test_labels[test_class_id]))

confidence = out[0][test_class_id]
print("* confidence: {:.4f}".format(confidence.item()))
```

###### error ?

```
* shape:  torch.Size([1, 1000])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X.py", line 121, in <module>
    print("* class ID: {}, label: {}".format(test_class_id, test_labels[test_class_id]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

###### How is this possible while i'm using the same img and same model ?

Comment: I've experienced a slight difference in OpenCV inference vs. the original framework, but when the difference is a lot there is something wrong in blob parameters. Check the pytorch preprocess on the input image and do the same for opencv. In your code, check mean and channel swap and maybe the need to divide by standard deviation. I suggest you to test also onnx-runtime.

Comment: Dont use cv2.dnn.blobFromImage for grayscale image. Single channel input does not need any channel splitting.

Comment: In input_img=cv2.imread('image.bmp',cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) do t use the COLOR_BGR2GRAY tag, which is for cv2.cvtColor function. Use cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE instead.

Comment: @Micka when I use "cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE" I'm getting this error and i have to use my image with grayscale Error: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,224,224) doesn't match the broadcast shape (3,224,224)

Comment: @iGian my input image parameters look the same compare with my PyTorch code. Somehow it works with OpenCV DNN but when I use the same methods for PyTorch in the same .py code file then gives me this wrong shape (torch.Size([1, 1000])
 even the image is the same

Comment: my pytorch transforms   :                                                                  
 eval_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=3),
    transforms.Resize((224,224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    #transforms.Normalize(mean, std)
])

Comment: Ok, this means you input of the network is 3 channels and so you will need the blobFromImage. Why did you choose the BGR2GRAY flag? Is there a special reason? Better remove it completely.

Comment: Does your network neee RGB or BGR input?

Comment: @Micka no sir tätsachlich brauche ich nur gray Bilder .Aber habe ich es bemerkt,dass mein Pytorch Teil des Codes "pretrained Imagenet" dataset benutzt.Darum gib mein program mir torch.size(1,1000). Wenn ich dieser Cod = original_model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True) benutzt ,dann geht schief etwas mit model

Comment: You need grayscale but 3 channels? Then load BGR (remove COLOR_BGR2GRAY) and use afterwards cv2.cvtColor with that flag. COLOR_BGR2GRAY is not an assumed parameter value in imread, I dont know to which IMREAD_ flag its integer value corresponds.

Comment: I think you can get some help from somebody if you could share your code (e.g with a Colab notebook), inclusive of the export to onnx part.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. The problem was the model. I was using here resnet 50 pretrained but I need my model so I used these lines to solve and its worked.

```
model = models.resnet50(pretrained = True)
model.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=2, bias=True)
weights = torch.load('model_best.pth',map_location ='cpu')
model.load_state_dict(weights)
model.eval()
```

gives me same opencv outputs

```
PyTorch model prediction: 

* shape:  torch.Size([1, 2])
* class ID: 1, label: 323
* confidence: 8.4153
```